# Rendering all the cells of UITableview at once to generate tableview screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a view controller with the below UI layout.

There is a header view at the top with 3 labels, a footer view with 2 buttons at the bottom  and an uitableview inbetween header view and footer view.  The uitableview is dynamically loaded and on average has about 6 tableview cells.  One of the buttons in the footer view is take screenshot button where i need to take the screenshot of full tableview. In small devices like iPhone 6,  the height of the table is obviously small as it occupies the space between header view and footer view. So only 4 cells are visible to the user and as the user scrolls others cells are loaded into view.  If the user taps take screen shot button without scrolling the table view, **the last 2 cells are not captured in the screenshot.**  The current implementation tried to negate this by changing table view frame to table view content size before capturing screenshot and resetting frame after taking screenshot,  but this approach is not working starting iOS 13 as the table view content size returns incorrect values.

[Current UI layout implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ghbj.png)

Our first solution is to embed the tableview inside the scrollview and have the tableview's scroll disabled. By this way the tableview will be forced to render all cells at once.  We used the below custom table view class to override intrinsicContentSize to make the tableview adjust itself to correct height based on it contents

```
class CMDynamicHeightAdjustedTableView: UITableView {

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
     self.layoutIfNeeded()
     return self.contentSize
  }

  override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet {
     self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
  }


  override func reloadData() {
      super.reloadData()
      self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
  }
}
```

[Proposed UI implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evi8j.png)

But we are little worried about how overriding intrinsicContentSize could affect performance and other apple's internal implementations

So our second solution is to set a default initial height constraint for tableview and observe the tableview's content size keypath and update the tableview height constraint accordingly. But the content size observer gets called atleast 12-14 times before the screen elements are visible to the user.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.confirmationTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

}

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "contentSize" {
        if object is UITableView {
            if let newvalue = change?[.newKey], let newSize = newvalue as? CGSize {
                self.confirmationTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Will the second approach impact performance too?
2. What is the better approach of the two?
3. Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: Not understanding the problem. Are you saying when you take a screenshot an area of the screen is not being captured (i.e. the missing cells) or that you want to take a screenshot of something that is not actually on the screen?

Comment: Do you want to capture the Header, Footer and all Rows? Or, just the Rows?

Comment: Ah - your "Header" and "Footer" views are ***not*** `.tableViewHeaderView` / `.tableViewFooterView` ... I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if I understood correctly when you screenshot the TableView the last 2 cells are not loaded because of the tableview being between the Header and Footer. Here are two options I would consider:

### Option 1

Try to make the TableView frame start from the Header and have the height of the Unscreen.main.bounds.height - the Header view frame. This would mean that the tableView will expand toward the end of the screen. Then add the Footer over the tableView in the desired relation.

### Option 2

Try before screenshooting, to reloadRows at two level below the current Level. You can get the current indexPath of the UITableView, when the TableView reloads it from its delegate, store it somewhere always the last indexPath used, and when screenshot reload the two below.

Comment: Our problem is because the table view is basically a recycle view,  all the cells are not available during screenshot. Setting table view frame to table view content size does not work anymore

Comment: Can you set the tableview frame by using the UIScreen main bounds, and decrementing the size of the footer?

Answer (score 0):

You can "temporarily" change the height of your table view, force it to update, render it to a `UIImage`, and then set the height back.

Assuming you have your "Header" view constrained to the top, your "Footer" view constrained to the bottom, and your table view constrained between them...

Add a class var/property for the table view's bottom constraint:

```
var tableBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

then set that constraint:

```
tableBottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
```

When you want to "capture" the table:

```
func captureTableView() -> UIImage {
    // save the table view's bottom constraint's constant
    //  and the contentOffset y position
    let curConstant = tableBottomConstraint.constant
    let curOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y
    
    // make table view really tall, to guarantee all rows will fit
    tableBottomConstraint.constant = 20000
    
    // force it to update
    tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tableView.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    // get the image
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    // set table view state back to what it was
    tableBottomConstraint.constant = curConstant
    tableView.contentOffset.y = curOffset

    return image
}
```

Here is a complete example you can run to test it:

```
class SimpleCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
}

class TableCapVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    // let's use 12 rows, each with 1, 2, 3 or 4 lines of text
    //  so it will definitely be too many rows to see on the screen
    let numRows: Int = 12
    
    var tableBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // we'll use this to display that captured table view image
    let resultHolder = UIView()
    let resultImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let headerView = myHeaderView()
        let footerView = myFooterView()
        
        [headerView, tableView, footerView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // we will use this to change the bottom constraint of the table view
        //  when we want to capture it
        tableBottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain "header" view at the top
            headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain "fotter" view at the bottom
            footerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            footerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            footerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain table view between header and footer views
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            tableBottomConstraint,
            
        ])

        tableView.register(SimpleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // we'll add a UIImageView (in a "holder" view) on top of the table
        //  then show/hide it to see the results of
        //  the table capture
        resultImageView.backgroundColor = .gray
        resultImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        resultImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        resultImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
        resultImageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        resultImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        resultImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        resultImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
        resultImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        resultHolder.alpha = 0.0
        
        resultHolder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        resultImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        resultHolder.addSubview(resultImageView)
        view.addSubview(resultHolder)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // cover everything with the clear "holder" view
            resultHolder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            resultHolder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            resultHolder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            resultHolder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            resultImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resultHolder.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            resultImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resultHolder.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            resultImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resultHolder.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            resultImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resultHolder.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        // tap image view / holder view when showing to hide it
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideImage))
        resultHolder.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    func myHeaderView() -> UIView {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.spacing = 4
        let strs: [String] = [
            "\"Header\" and \"Footer\" views",
            "are separate views - they are not",
            ".tableHeaderView / .tableFooterView",
        ]
        strs.forEach { str in
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = str
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .regular)
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
            sv.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.addSubview(sv)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        return v
    }
    
    func myFooterView() -> UIView {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.axis = .horizontal
        sv.spacing = 12
        sv.distribution = .fillEqually
        let btn1: UIButton = {
            var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
            cfg.title = "Capture Table"
            let b = UIButton(configuration: cfg)
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btn1Action(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return b
        }()
        let btn2: UIButton = {
            var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
            cfg.title = "Another Button"
            let b = UIButton(configuration: cfg)
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btn2Action(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return b
        }()
        sv.addArrangedSubview(btn1)
        sv.addArrangedSubview(btn2)
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.addSubview(sv)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        return v
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numRows
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
        let nLines = indexPath.row % 4
        var s: String = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        for i in 0..<nLines {
            s += "\nLine \(i+2)"
        }
        c.theLabel.text = s
        return c
    }

    @objc func btn1Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let img = captureTableView()
        print("TableView Image Captured - size:", img.size)
        
        // do something with the tableView capture
        //  maybe save it to documents folder?
        
        // for this example, we will show it
        resultImageView.image = img
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.resultHolder.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
    @objc func hideImage() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.resultHolder.alpha = 0.0
        })
    }
    @objc func btn2Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Another Button Tapped")
    }
    
    func captureTableView() -> UIImage {
        // save the table view's bottom constraint's constant
        //  and the contentOffset y position
        let curConstant = tableBottomConstraint.constant
        let curOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y
        
        // make table view really tall, to guarantee all rows will fit
        tableBottomConstraint.constant = 20000
        
        // force it to update
        tableView.setNeedsLayout()
        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tableView.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        // get the image
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        
        // set table view state back to what it was
        tableBottomConstraint.constant = curConstant
        tableView.contentOffset.y = curOffset

        return image
    }
    
}
```

We give the table 12 rows, each with 1, 2, 3 or 4 lines of text so it will definitely be too many rows to see on the screen. Tapping on the "Capture Table" button will capture the table to a `UIImage` and then display that image. Tap on the image to dismiss it:

[image]

[image]